# Parameterized methods in generic class type

Tags: java, generics, parameterized

I have a rather simple question. I can't find an answer by searching though.

Is there a difference in these two code-fragments? And what is the difference?

Fragment1:

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
   ...
   public <E extends T> void add(E value) {
      ...
   }

   public <E extends T> void add(E value, Node node) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Fragment2:

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
   ...
   public void add(T value) {
      ...
   }

   public void add(T value, Node node) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Fragment1 specifies explicitly, that the parameter *value* must be either of type *T* or a subtype of type *T*.

Fragment2 specifies, that the parameter *value* must be of type *T*. But from my little knowledge and experience I think that I can also supply a subtype of *T* here. So same as fragment1.

I looked at the disassembled byte codes of these two fragments. Indeed there is a difference:

```
<   public <E extends T> void add(E);
---
>   public void add(T);
```

That just reflects the source code ...

I just don't get the meaning. And I also can't find an example application, which shows the difference.

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Where did these fragments come from? Is this homework / coursework?

Comment: The fragments are form a book. The author is claiming to improve the class by moving from fragment2 to fragment1. I was not able to reconstruct his explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case there is no difference. Let's take for example a `BinaryTree<Number>` and try adding an `Integer`:

```
BinaryTree<Number> numTree = new BinaryTree<>();
Integer i = 1;
numTree.add(i);
```

With fragment 1, `E` may evaluate to `Integer`, but that's superfluous in this case. `Integer` *is a* `Number`, and you could just as well specify `Number` for `E`:

```
numTree.<Number>add(i);
```

For this reason the second snippet is no different than the first, and less confusing for not declaring an unnecessary type parameter.

---

There are situations where an additional type parameter would be useful. Imagine for some reason you wanted to return the passed in value:

```
public <E extends T> E add(E value) {
   ...
   return value;
}

public <E extends T> E add(E value, Node node) {
   ...
   return value;
}
```

This would now be useful to the caller:

```
Integer i2 = numTree.add(i);
```

With the second snippet that wouldn't be possible, and `numTree.add` could only return a `Number` even if you passed in an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference between the two variations of the `add()` method. Java's method arguments already establish an *upper bound* on the accepted type, which is the same constraint accomplished by using the `extends` form of your type variable `<E extends T>`.

Your type variable adds no new information nor does it add any additional constraints. It was already legal to pass an argument of type `T` *or any type that extends `T`*. Your type variable `<E extends T>` does provide a way to refer to the actual argument type again—say, if there was a second method parameter that you wanted to ensure was of the same type as the first—but in your case, you're not making use of `E`.