# Generics and Parameterized Constructors

Tags: java

This is an extension of this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130940/parameterized-methods-in-generic-class-type) about parameterized methods. I am reading the same book. After the example in the previous question, the author improves the

```
BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

class yet again (and he really does this time around) by adding the following constructor

```
public  <E extends T> BinaryTree(E[] items) {
    for(E item : items) {
        add(item);
}
```

In the spirit of the previous question I tried this constructor instead:

```
public BinaryTree(T[] items) {
    for(T item : items) {
        add(item);
    }
}
```

and the example code does not compile with my constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Manager[] managers = { new Manager("Jane", 1), new Manager("Joe", 3), new Manager("Freda", 3), new Manager("Bert", 2), new Manager("Ann", 2), new Manager("Dave", 2) };
    BinaryTree<Person> people = new BinaryTree<>(managers);
}
```

What is this difference between changing the add() method in the previous question and changing this constructor? Why can't I pass a subtype of T in my constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd constructor, when compiler sees

```
new BinaryTree<>(managers)
```

it needs to infer `T` for the `<>`. In this case, inference is based on `managers`: `T[]=Manager[] => T=Manager`.

Therefore the expression yields a `BinaryTree<Manager>`, which cannot be assigned to `BinaryTree<Person>`.

Two workarounds:

```
new BinaryTree<Person>(managers);

new BinaryTree((Person[])managers);
```

---

For the 1st constructor

```
<E extends T> BinaryTree(E[] items)
```

we have two things to infer now, `E` and `T`, in expression `new BinaryTree<>(managers)`

Now `E=Manager` is inferred; however `T` is not inferred yet. The compiler then looks at the target type `Binary<Person>`, which helps to infer that `T=Person`.

---

Java type inference is quite messy. Why would any programmer care to learn what I have just described? The lesson is, when in doubt, supply type arguments explicitly.

Between the two constructors, I would definitely choose `BinaryTree(T[] items)`. The `E` version is just more complexity without benefits (though it happens to work better for this particular example)

Comment: This all makes sense, thanks. So I guess there is not much of point in using <E extends T> BinaryTree(E[] items)

Comment: There's no point, since the `T[]` arg would accept any `X[]` where `X` is subtype of `T`. Note this won't work for `List`. If we want to accept any `List<X>` where `X` is subtype of `T`, we need `List<? extends T>` as the arg type.